# Using jQuery UI Dialog, how can I load content from another webpage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The title says everything exept one thing: I dont want to add a `<div id="something"></div>` in the body of my webpage.

I found this on the internet:

```
var $mklib = $('<div></div>')
        .html('test')
        .dialog({
            title: "Create a library",
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fade",
            hide: "fade",
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 150,
            width: 300,
            buttons: { "Create": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close"); }
                },      
        });
$( ".open_mklib" ).click(function() {
    $mklib.dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});
```

But I need the `.html('test')` to be `'load_that_*****_page.php'`

And off topic, I need the create button to send the form that will be inside the `load_that_*****_page.php`...

Any superhuman to the rescue?

Thanks a lot!

---

Okay guys I got it on the internet, here is the code, but when I click Submit, it doesnt work! :P
(URL: http://magix-cjquery.com/post/2010/08/01/jquery-ui-dialog-avec-soumission-de-formulaire-ajax)

```
$('.open_mklib').live("click",function(){
        var box_url = "./functions/modal.php";
            var form_url = "./";
        $("#mklib").load(box_url, function() {
                $(this).dialog({
                            title: 'New Library',
                        height: 'auto',
                        width:'auto',
                            resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        position: 'center',
                        overlay: {
                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                opacity: 0.5
                        },
                        buttons: {
                                'Submit': function() {
                                        $("#mklib form").ajaxSubmit({
                                                url: box_url,
                                                type: "post",
                                                error: function(){
                                                        alert("theres an error with AJAX");
                                                },
                                                beforeSubmit:function(){},
                                                success: function(e){}
                                        });
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                },
                                'Cancel': function() {
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
                        }
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: You said "The title say everything exept one thing", but I didn't understand what the title said. I changed it to: "Using a jQuery UI Dialog, how can I load content from another webpage?". Is that what you're asking?

Comment: (Really sorry Josh my english is really bad so maybe I think it's really clear and understandable, but it's probably all the inverse)

Comment: @Jeremy: Not to worry, that's why we're here to help! I just wanted to make sure I didn't **change the meaning** of your question when I changed the title. :-)

Comment: @Josh oh okay thanks I appreciate. People seems to be very friendly around here :)

Comment: @Jeremy, you want the dynamic content to be the text inside the dialog box?

Comment: Yep -- Sorry I'm new and I never notified the little (More comments (1) link) :S Sorry

Comment: Jeremy, did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Would this fancy you? Never did this before, but theoretically, I would assume you have to load your php first, and then wrap that in the dialog on success.

Also I included a second ajax call in your close.

```
var $mklib = $('<div></div>')
    .ajax({type: "GET", url: blah_blah.php,  dataType: "script", success: function(){
      .dialog({
          title: "Create a library",
          autoOpen: false,
          show: "fade",
          hide: "fade",
          draggable: false,
          resizable: false,
          height: 150,
          width: 300,
          buttons: { "Create": function() {
              $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "whever_this_goes.php", data: $("#yourForm").serialize(), success: function(){$(this).dialog("close") })}
              },      
      }); 
   }
});

$( ".open_mklib" ).click(function() {
    $mklib.dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much, I don't know how you done that but thanks! --EDIT:-- Oups! Dreamweaver CS5 warn me about an error on line : .dialog({ And I tried to figure where is the error, but since I'm new to jQuery, there is too much { } and ( ) for me... LOL

Comment: (Original post edited, see above for the new code)... Still not working... Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).dialog()` on line 3? @Jeremy try that

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I added $(this) on line 3 but now DW CS5 sais error on line 13: $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "whever_thi[...]

Comment: No one want to give it a try? :P